# I am getting this error when executing Testng in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng-dataprovider

Data Provider `public java.lang.Object[] as.get()` must return either `Object[][]` or `Iterator<Object>[]`, not class `java.lang.Object;`

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) says:

> The Data Provider method can return one of the following two types:
>
> - An array of array of objects (**`Object[][]`**) where the first dimension's
>     size is the number of times the test method will be invoked and the
>     second dimension size contains an array of objects that must be
>     compatible with the parameter types of the test method. This is the
>     cast illustrated by the example above.
> - An **`Iterator<Object[]>`**. The only
>     difference with Object[][] is that an Iterator lets you create your
>     test data lazily. TestNG will invoke the iterator and then the test
>     method with the parameters returned by this iterator one by one. This
>     is particularly useful if you have a lot of parameter sets to pass to
>     the method and you don't want to create all of them upfront.

So, I suppose you current data provider method is returning `Object` instead of one of the 2 supported types.